# how to find a solution for the runqemu error?

Tags: embedded-linux

I am getting this error, after use this command `runqemu qemux86 nographic`

```sh
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemux86 bitbake -e ...
runqemu - ERROR - /root/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86 not a directory valid DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE
ls: cannot access '/root/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/*.qemuboot.conf': No such file or directory
runqemu - ERROR - Command 'ls -t /root/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/*.qemuboot.conf' returned non-zero exit status 2.
runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. check path, whitch shown in second line "runqemu - ERROR - /root/.../qemux86 not a directory valid DEPLOY_DIR_IMAG"
2. I my case folder ".../quemux86" was missing, but there was a dirrectory ".../quemux86-64"
3. ln -s qemux86-64 qemux86 - fix the problem
   :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. But, I don't even know why, it works when I run the following.

```
runqemu
```

So maybe that could help.